# Skype Geo Locator uninstall

Tags: plugins, skype, uninstall

In spite of some negative rewiew the functionality of Skype Geo Located seemede interesting to me and I decided to give it a try. I did not like the utility, though, and now I would like to uninstall it. I have already uninstalled the Skype extra, however the utility is still messing with my Skype "motto" and it also seems to be somehow present in Firefox (it is not listed as the extension, though).

Can anyone provide specific instructions how to uninstall this utility completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the exe and its startup shortcut manually. It was a time ago and I do not remember its exact location, but I think it was in the Skype extras folder.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the [**automaticly start extras**] undeder skype/advanced settings to be sure the extra won't load. you may have to clear the skype cookies. or maybe that extas has modified some skype core components so a uninstall/reinstall should fix that.